# "java.lang.AssertionError: Expected visible but was not visible" in Robolectric test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Why does the following test fail with the error given in the title?

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBaseballCardDetails() {
        FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.EDIT_CARD);

        assertThat(fragment).isNotNull().isAdded().isVisible();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to call `visible()` on the `ActivityController`:

```
mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
```